# Decoding ampersand (&amp) to normal

Tags: php, html

I am having problems creating add file form which if person wants, it redirects after submit to add new file, but when I try to do that it still redirects back to m=files because it shows `?m=files&amp;a=addedit`. I tried using html_entity_decode, but still it shows the same `?m=files&amp;a=addedit` what to do, here is my redirect?

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $new = html_entity_decode('m=files&amp;a=addedit'); ?>" />
```

Comment: You are saying `because it shows ?m=files&a=addedit.` of-course it will show this .... as you are writing this via PHP in `value=`

Comment: `echo $new = 'xxx'` ? why do you affect it to a variable, it may break the echo...

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want that it would show normaly ?m=files&a=addedit

Comment: It's hard to understand... you say **it shows ?m=files&a=addedit**, and you say you want to show **?m=files&a=addedit** what's the problem ?

Comment: Nah it shows with &amp and i need &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what OP wants, but simply replacing `&amp` with `&` should solve the problem, I think.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo str_replace('&amp;', '&', 'm=files&amp;a=addedit'); ?>" />
```

Comment: It still change from & to &amp;