# Swiftmailer Ampersand Decoding Issue (&amp;)

Tags: php, swiftmailer, ampersand, getparameter

I've got a weird problem with Swiftmailer 5.x:

```
  $mailUrl = htmlspecialchars("$serverDiff/test/?action=passwordreset&token=$user_token");
  $mailtext = "Für Ihren Account wurde das Zurücksetzen des Passwortes veranlasst. Bitte gehen Sie über folgenden Link, um dies einzugeben: $mailUrl";
  $mailtext = $textclass->text($mailtext);
```

This always returns `&amp; token=` which, of course, is wrong. No matter how often I try to utf8_decode, encode, htmlspecialchars it or just try using the xhtml or unicode for the ampersand it still switches to `&amp;`

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? I already asked a bunch of colleagues and friends and no one knows ...
Thank you very much!

Comment: The question isn't clear. Is `$mailtext` set to `&amp; token=` after those three lines? If so, what is textclass and the text() method doing?

Comment: Nope, it was being changed by a later framework function called setBody. See answer beneath, please. But thank you for answering / commenting.

Answer (score 0):

I finally soluted this with the help of another post that lead me right to the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31426274/2181606

Just went into the framework (/swiftmailer-5.x/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/MimePart.php) in line 64 (setBody function) and inserted this (see line 2, first is just for positioning reference):

```
    $body = $this->_convertString($body);
    $body = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $body);
```

Thank you, me. :D